# Send file from folder to Java .jar file as parameter/argument?

Tags: c#, jar, lua, executable-jar

I'm writing a C# program that extracts several compiled Lua scripts. Basically what I want to do is create a process of a lua .jar decompiler, then send all of the extracted files into the decompiler by supplying it with the file's path and name.

The java .jar file, unluac.jar, is in the same folder as my C# executable.

```
Process doctorProc = new Process();
doctorProc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("unluac.jar", "-jar unluac.jar" + Path.Combine(selectedDirectory, newFileDirectory));
doctorProc.StartInfo.FileName = "unluac.jar";
doctorProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
doctorProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
doctorProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
doctorProc.Start();
String luaScript = doctorProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(finalOutputDirectory,fileName), luaScript);
doctorProc.WaitForExit();
```

This is what I've got. The path it is being supplied with is vague,
it's basically combining `C:\" with "\Users\Dan\script1.lua`

When I extract, it calls this function. I do not see the java program open at any point, and when it reaches the StandardOutput it gives me an exception.

> {"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."}

This is very strange, I'm not sure I understand the issue. I'm on Windows 10 using unluac.jar, which I've used plenty of times to decompile scripts.

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong as I'm fairly inexperienced as a programmer. But if this error is fixed, the rest of this might not be written correctly, I'm a bit lost on how to do this.

I would love either a way to fix this current code or a better way of doing it. I tried to make this post simple, but if I missed any important information, please let me know. I would be more than happy to add anything that is needed. I'm confident I've made mistakes, but the opportunity to fix them and learn from them would be excellent.

Thanks a bunch, everyone. I appreciate the help!

**Edit:** I solved a few of the issues, but still have errors. Originally the program could not find the unluac.jar because I failed to give it the working directory. I also needed to redirectstandardoutput then set useexecutable shell to false, but I still have a new error about incorrect OS. Thanks!

**Edit 2:** I no longer receive any errors about OS after changing the StartInfo.FileName to "java" instead of "unluac.jar".
The java program pops open for a second before I get another exception:

> {"Access to the path 'C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\22222\Decompiled\WildStar\pov\BinCommon\Scripts\Experimental' is denied."}

My program has written files via File.WriteAllBytes and File.WriteAllText before, always to the same folder in my desktop. I have added an assembly manifest and given the program elevated privileges, but it still gives the same exception.

**Edit 3:** I fixed the previous problem by supplying the directory with a fileName as well. Currently, the java program is running and my program is iterating through all of the files I needed to send it, but for some reason the output for all of the files is empty. They have the write name and are in the correct folder, but are all 0kb.

I suspect this might have to do with the program trying to read the output of the .jar file, which leads me to think I still have a problem with how my files are being input or how I am catching the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a series of problems with my code, I updated as I got through them.
This was the final code I had that functions correctly.

```
doctorProc.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
doctorProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar unluac.jar " + fileDirectory;
File.Open((selectedDirectory + newFileDirectory), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)));
doctorProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
doctorProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
doctorProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
doctorProc.Start();
String luaScript = doctorProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(finalOutputDirectory,fileName), luaScript);
doctorProc.WaitForExit();
```

The main issue was what I was entering into the program. The program takes -jar unluac.exe  which is what is now updated to do.
My issue was compounded by other errors as documented above, as well as the final issue being a small error with my export format.

So this final code works, my errors are resolved. Hopefully this might perhaps help someone looking to do something similar.

Also, there was previously a person who commented and helped me, but deleted their post because it I had resolved that particular issue. Regardless, a big thanks to him! I really do appreciate the assistance!

And thanks to those who edited my question, it helps me learn to make better posts in the future.